# Reset application specific or phone-wide default image folder

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, default-applications

I was browsing with the official Facebook app and when sending a picture to a friend I used SkyDrive as the folder where to choose my files from. Then I accidentally made it the default folder. So now, whenever I want to send an image, the app always directs me to SkyDrive instead of getting it from the phone's gallery.

I already tried resetting to defaults and deleting the data of the app, but that didn't work. That's why I think it might be a phone-wide setting. I just can't seem to figure it out.

Phone is a Desire X, running Android 4.1.1.

Comment: Did you reset the defaults for SkyDrive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is to reset all the defaults:

```
Settings > Apps > Menu > Restore App preferences (or something, I have a Dutch version installed)
```